Adding Strapi to PM2 on Windows
I have a problem. I’m trying to add a strapi app to pm2 with the following command “pm2 start npm --name your-app-name – run start”, it is added but it instantly appears in PM2 with errored status. I attach the error log img. I’ve already searched everywhere but I can’t find a way to skip that error.
I've tried this command “pm2 start npm --name your-app-name – run start” expecting add the strapi app to PM2
